# Remote SSIS Management Visual Studio 2017 .Net Core 2.1.100-preview-007363

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to start a SSIS package located on SqlServer. This code works in .net framework 4.5.2 but in dotnet core I get an error.

**Code:**

```
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
var ssis = new IntegrationServices(sqlConnection); // Error on this line of code
var catalog = ssis.Catalogs["CatalogName"];
var folder = catalog.Folders["FolderName"];
var project = folder.Projects["ProjectName"];
var package = project.Packages["PackageName"];
```

**Error**

> Error CS7069 Reference to type 'SqlConnection' claims it is defined in 'System.Data', but it could not be found

**Assemblies**

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
System.Data.SqlClient.dll // <-- Via nuget
```

I there something that I am missing?

Comment: what version are you using? try to download the nuget again. https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/ and get the latest version

Comment: @JericCruz I am using 4.4.2 which is the latest version right now.

Comment: @Dblock247 - did you ever get this working?  I'm running into the same issue, tried various suggestions about packaging up assemblies as a local nuget, all to no avail.  Would like to get this to work vs using SqlClient to use the `EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].* ` technique

Comment: @CaseyR No I never figured it out. I was for a test project so I didn't keep after the solution.